# mongodb query behaviour on how this particular query works

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDb query:

> 

```
async(ids,divisionId)=>{
    try{
      var widgets=await Widgets.find({_id:{$in:ids},divisionId:divisionId})
      console.log(widgets)
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
}
```

I want to understand in detail how it works. If _id and divisionId do not match it produces an empty array but suppose some widgets do not have divisonId then I don't understand how it works.

For example I have this data in widgets with no division id

```
{ _id: 5aeae87d44b0a40a63cdb7fc,
 type: 'website',
 description: 'hhhh',
 index: 8,
 __v: 0,
 required: false,
 flag: '',
 content: ''
}
```

When i query with this data with _id and a division id I think it should not show me this data but it show me this data, can someone explain why?
thanks!

Comment: Technically, it shouldn't show it. I just verified it from the shell. Maybe you can try adding a condition `{divisionId: {$exists: true}}`

Comment: Note that `divisionId` on the "right hand side"` is a variable. So it depends on what is inside it. You can `console.log(divisionId)` to see what it actually contains, but really you should see this being set in the code. You really need to show the context. So the variables that should also be present in the code are `ids` and `divisisionId`. Find them and tell us what they are if you still don't understand.

Comment: @NeilLunn yes they are variable that i get in from other place like ids content ids=[ 
        ObjectId("5aeadb6fe8c0430954ed7305"), 
        ObjectId("5aeadb6fe8c0430954ed7306"), 
        ObjectId("5aeadb6fe8c0430954ed7307"), 
        ObjectId("5aeadb6fe8c0430954ed7308"), 
        ObjectId("5aeaeb5287e43c0aad18668f"), 
        ObjectId("5aeae87d44b0a40a63cdb7fc")
    ] and divisionId=ObjectId("5aea88fa1cd6810466e6bbbf")

Comment: You need to edit the question and show us more of the code. You're missing something obvious and we cannot see what is not in front of us

Comment: @NeilLunn i have edited it.